# dom manipulation

Tags: jquery, dom

iam using **jquery** and want to do below written

```
    //this is a template
     <div class='main'>
    <div class='header'>Some Text</div>
    <div class='data'>
    // data goes here
    </div>
    </div>
```

// dom

```
 --------dom here-------------
<div id='red1' class='red'></div>
-----more dom (template is here)------------
```

what i want is, to bind template to any element(lets  say id=red1) to have resulting dom as written below

//below is new dom

```
    --------dom here-------------
     <div class='main'>
    <div class='header'>Some Text</div>
    <div class='data'>
// element is wrapped with template
    <div id='red1' class='red'></div>
    </div>
    </div>
-----more dom (**template is still here**)------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
// Capture the wrapper template html
var wrapper = $('<div class="main"><div class="header">Some Text</div><div class="data"></div></div>');

// Then replace the "red1" div with the wrapper and since the replaceWith 
// method returns the replaced element, you can just append it right back to your data div  
$('#red1').replaceWith(wrapper).appendTo(wrapper.find('.data'));
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have a built in templating mechanism, but there are a lot of JavaScript libs out there that provide it. [mustache.js](http://github.com/scottymac/mustache.js) is one I like. [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template), which is a good complement to jQuery, also has a simple template function.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use the [wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) function to wrap the template around divs with that id.